# IF statement error message in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The following formula is returning a `#VALUE!` error.

```
=IF(L$3<$H11,4*5,(IF("<0",0,(5-(L$3-$H11))*4)))
```

Why is it returning an error?  I know that the error is coming from somewhere in the second IF statement but I can't figure out why.

Comment: What is it you want to check if is smaller than 0 in the second if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Let's deconstruct this thing

```
=if(condition,True,False)
=IF(L$3<$H11,4*5,(IF("<0",0,(5-(L$3-$H11))*4)))
```

so, L3 < H11 `goto` 4*5 - OK

L3 >= H11 `goto` If("<0",0,(5-L3-H11))*4 - OK

```
=If("<0",0,(5-L3-H11))*4
```

Let's try this one:

If "<0" `goto` 0 else `goto` 5-L3-H11*4

What is this `if` checking? `=if("<0")` doesn't return a `true` or `false` so..error.

---

So this is called [nested](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php)`if` [statements](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/IF-function-a918d97a-251e-4af5-bd15-09b12b8742bb). Let me show you an example -

```
=if(A2>A1,"a2 is greater",if(A2=A1,"they are the same","A1 is greater"))
```

See the first if is checking A2 > A1. If it isn't then **it forgets everything from before and goes to the second if**. This one is checking if A2 = A1 and then returning a TRUE or a FALSE

You need a condition in the nested `if` as they don't carry through.

Comment: The second if statement is there because I need to have a way of returning a 0 value instead of a negative value which is what the formula outputs when it's written as (L3<h11,4*5,(5-(L3-H11)*4). So I tried adding in the second IF statement to resolve that third condition.

Comment: Your second IF statement isn't a question - all you've fed it is the literal string `"<0"`.

I assume you meant to check if `L$3<0` and if so, return `0`?

Comment: Just as @SilasB mentioned, the error is because the `if` isn't checking anything to return `true` or `false`. If says "what" and then there's an error. It can't make it to the conditions of true or false.

Comment: @Paul I added an example, does that help?

Comment: @Paul I'm glad we could help. If you've solved your problem, click the green check-mark next to the answer that helped - this will mark the problem as solved.